# Checking String with is_numeric in C

Tags: c

I am a newbie in stack exchange code review. I just wrote a C function where the function checks if the given string is numeric or not. What do you think about my way of doing this? And could this be done in other ways?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_numeric(const char* str)
{
    while (isspace(*str))
       str++;
    
    if (*str == '-' || *str == '+')
       str++;

    while (*str)
    {
        if (!isdigit(*str) && !isspace(*str))
            return false;
        str++;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("%s\n", is_numeric("123436")  ? "true" : "false"); // should be true
  printf("%s\n", is_numeric("123.436") ? "true" : "false"); // should be false
  printf("%s\n", is_numeric("    567") ? "true" : "false"); // should be true
  printf("%s\n", is_numeric("235   ")  ? "true" : "false"); // should be true
  printf("%s\n", is_numeric("794,347") ? "true" : "false"); // should be false
  printf("%s\n", is_numeric("hello")   ? "true" : "false"); // should be false
  printf("%s\n", is_numeric("-3423")   ? "true" : "false"); // should be true
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider changing the return type to `bool` (defined in stdbool as of C99)

Comment: @elyashiv that's a good idea. thanks :)

Comment: If it is performance critical code, calling `isdigit` and `isspace` is not a good idea. 

They can be done without introducing the function overhead in a single line by comparing characters directly.

`if ((*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') || *str == ' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bug**: `is_numeric("")` returns true.

**Bug**: `is...(negative_values)` is UB.  (Aside from `is...(EOF)`).  Possible when `*str < 0`.

**Bugs**: as reported by [user3629249](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/245756/29485)

---

- Consider allowing hex such as `"0xAbC"`.
- Standard library *string* functions operate as if `char` is *unsigned*, even if `char` is *signed*.  Recommend to do the same here.

> What do you think about my way of doing this?

I like the idea of allowing  of trailing white-space when leading white-space allowed.

---

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>   // missing in OP code.

bool is_numeric_integer(const char *str) {
  const unsigned char *ustr = (const unsigned char *) str;
  while (isspace(*ustr)) {
    ustr++;
  }
    
  if (*ustr == '-' || *ustr == '+') {
    ustr++;
  }

  const unsigned char *begin = ustr;
  while (isdigit(*ustr)) {
    ustr++;
  }
  if (begin == ustr) {
    return false; // no digits.
  }

  // If you want to allow trailing white-space
  while (isspace(*ustr)) {
    ustr++;
  }

  return *ustr == '\0';  // fail with trailing junk
}
```

Answer (score 3):

regarding:

```
if (!isdigit(*str) && !isspace(*str))
```

the `isdigit()` handles 0...9, so catches if any of the passed in char array is not numeric.

The `&& !isspace(*str))`  has nothing to do with numeric values

Comment: I was thinking about the trailing spaces, that is why I did that. But you are right, this is going to give the wrong result if the input is "4545    5657" which I think it shouldn't.